# Is the conversion from HTML to DOM and back to HTML standardized?

Tags: html, dom, cross-browser, html-parsing, rich-text-editor

I'm working on an rich-text editor that will be using ContentEditable. It's imperative that a document that is loaded into the browser (from the web server) is not altered in any way by the conversion to DOM, and then back to HTML alone (assuming the user has not made any changes).

It's alright if the HTML document is modified the first time it's created and saved by a browser, but subsequently should not occur again, which simply requires that all browsers will produce the same DOM based on equivalent HTML, and the same HTML output based on equivalent DOMs. Is this something that I can rely upon?

Comment: ContentEditables will produce different results on different browsers. For example the first thing I can think of are apple styles in webskit browsers. But there will be many *many* more.

Comment: "all browsers will produce the same DOM", that'll be risky to bet on.

Comment: You don't even get the same html back when nothing is changed. e.g. Firefox inserts a tbody element before trs in the DOM, even  if there is no tbody in the html...

Comment: @BeniBela - every modern browser will probably do that since TBODY is required child of TABLE. (You can omit it from your markup according to HTML5 specs, but because its required, the browsers will implicity add it). If each browser complies with the spec you are using the same way they should adhere to the same rules, but that is still a big if.

Comment: What method are you using to serialize the DOM into markup?

Comment: @Alohci - OuterHTML if it's suitable. Otherwise, I'll have to figure out something else.

Comment: In that case, it's easy to demonstrate that the markup doesn't round-trip. Take markup that starts as `<div id='mydiv'></div>`. In IE9 that becomes `<div id="mydiv"></div>`. In IE8, it becomes `<DIV id=mydiv></DIV>`

Comment: @Alohci I'll mark that as the answer if you want to make one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to demonstrate that the markup doesn't round-trip when the serialisation is performed with innerHTML or outerHTML.

Take markup that starts as `<div id='mydiv'></div>`. In IE9 that becomes `<div id="mydiv"></div>`. In IE8, it becomes `<DIV id=mydiv></DIV>`