# JavaScript Implementation of DOM Level 2 (or better?)

Tags: javascript, dom, cross-browser

Due to the comments I received [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12331997/is-the-conversion-from-html-to-dom-and-back-to-html-standardized) I'm looking for a pure-javascript implementation of the DOM that will run in all common browsers. Please take note that I'm not looking to interact with the browsers implentation of the DOM (not even through jQuery). I'm looking for a complete replacement.

Edit: Since uncommon questions are occasionally met with criticism on SO, I'll attempt to explain why I need to do this. I'm writing a rich-text editor that needs some very specific features, and the implementation differences between browsers causes me to not be able to rely on them for consistency. Please see this answer to another question (related to my needs) [Definition of ExecCommand function for bold?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158503/definition-of-execcommand-function-for-bold/12166267#12166267) that elaborates on why this is necessary.

Comment: @pst I've edited my question so that maybe I can get some serious consideration instead of merely down votes. If you still feel that this is not necessary, then I will pass along your wisdom to one of the creators of CKEditor.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it always helps to explain a *practical reason* :) Considering that editors *rely heavily* on user-interaction, I do not see how a mere "DOM 2 replacement" would work .. it's all *a bunch of hacks* across browsers, as discussed in that linked answer.

Comment: This is a great question! I don't understand why people are downvoting. +1

Comment: @pst Key strokes are captured so that I can manipulate my own DOM. Copy, paste, undo, and redo will be using DOM mutation observers (with contentEditable enabled), and applying those differential changes to my own DOM. Changes that are made to my DOM trigger an update to the browsers DOM. This should enable me to tightly control precisely what happens when editing and to send/receive differential changes to/from the webapp's host. The documentation of CKEditor discusses a similar approach - the backing HTML/DOM implementation controlling the browsers'.

Answer (score 2):

[jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) is the canonical answer to this question. [dom.js](https://github.com/andreasgal/dom.js/) is another, but I don't know anyone who uses it, so I doubt it has seen much testing.

Comment: Thanks for the leads. I'm concerned about both of these inside common browsers. They're both intended for node.js, and I'm having trouble finding much discussing their success outside that environment.